# how to link purchases to user records in another system?

Tags: shopify

sorry I posted this in the google group before I realized you had moved this type of question to stackoverflow

I'm developing a web app with an e-commerce component based on shopify as a white-labelled product for our clients.  Our app allows our clients' customers to purchase a subscription to a product for use within the app.  Each of our clients will have a separate shopify store.  We have a web interface that allows our clients to create products and we use the shopify api to create the products in their store via an app.  We have installed web hooks to receive notification of payments so that we can create the appropriate records in our system to allow the customer access to the product they purchased.

So far, the plan has been to provide a product list on our site with a 'Buy Now' button that adds the product to the store's cart and then direct the user to checkout using Shopify's checkout system.  In the fulfillment web hook, we get the cart token so all we need to do to link the two systems is record the cart token temporarily in our customer database and then we can credit the right user with the purchase.

The problem that we are running in to is that there seems to be no way to link the cart / order / payment to the user that is actually logged in to our system.  We are still under development so we are using test stores and the domain of the app is different from the domain of the store (and that may be the case in the production system too) and it is seemingly impossible to figure out how to link the two systems.

I have tried a couple of different approaches ...

1) use a form and post to the store's cart/add.js with a return_to=back

This seems successful in that the items are added to the cart and opening the cart in a new window takes them to the cart they added the item to, but there is no way to associate that cart with the user on our system since we can't access the cart token in a separate domain

2) use a proxy (our system is written in nodes) to post to the store's cart and intercept the cart token.

This also works in that an item is added to a cart and we can access the _session_id and cart cookies from the response, but I don't seem to be able to set those cookies in the browser.  Going to the store's cart doesn't show the item just added and the store gets a different cart token.

Is there a different approach or should one of those work?

Should we be doing this entirely differently?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to put something in cart attributes when the order is created and use that when you get the webhook to link the order to the other system. You could have a simple json endpoint on the other server to get back the currently logged in user, or have them enter some user is on the cart page and store them in the cart atributes. More on cart attributes http://wiki.shopify.com/Ask_customer_for_additional_information

Comment: Thanks John, I will try this out and follow up here.  I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve modifying the shopify pages at all, but I think this will work for the moment.  Is there a way to pass in a note or cart attribute via the /cart API calls when adding an item?  That's really all I need.

Comment: I've added the implementation of John's suggestion as an answer below because I didn't seem to be able to fit it into a comment and it didn't seem appropriate to modify the question.  John's solution is still not ideal for my purposes but I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

To implement John's suggestion, I put the following into my cart.liquid file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://<server>/token',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                $('#cartform').append('<input type="hidden" name="attributes[token]" value="'+data.token+'" />');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

My server runs on a different domain than the shop, so I'm using jsonp.  The token is something I can use to uniquely identify a customer record in my database. I am using an attribute so that it doesn't conflict with our client's use of shopify's note feature if they want to use it themselves for something.  I have not yet tested this with my web hook but I assume that I can make this work from here on.

I'm not completely satisfied with this as it requires that our clients put this into their templates in order for shopify to work with our system.  I still think that there should be a way through the JSON /cart API to set the value of the note for a cart.

Comment: What you could do instead is use a [ScriptTag](http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html) to insert this JS and use metafields instead of a note attribute visible to the user and merchant.

Comment: I had just come to the same conclusion, I have reduced this to having the client insert `<script src="http://<server>/shopify"></script>` which returns a jquery function on document.ready that injects a hidden input named attributes[token] with the value preset from the user's session on our server.  They still have to modify their cart templates but we can control the implementation more centrally at least.

Comment: To close the loop on this, I just successfully completed testing this with my order/paid web hook and was able to retrieve my user token from the attributes of the order.

Comment: In fact, using the ScriptTag API it is not necessary to have the client modify their cart at all.  The complete recipe is to include write_script_tags in your app scope, add a route in your code that returns a script that sets the custom attribute by injecting a hidden field into the cart, and look for that in your orders/paid web hook.  The script I used is ```(function($){$('#cartform').append('<input type="hidden" name="attributes[my_token]" value="token_value" />'})(jQuery);``` where I pull the token value out of the users session on the server side.